# How to rename workspaces on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: workspaces

I decided today to use workspaces on Ubuntu 20.04. I see that every workspace I create is named: `Workspace 1`, `Workspace 2`, etc.

Is there a way to rename that to meaningful names such as `Study`, `Video`, etc.?

P.S: Searching on Google doesn't return any useful results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a default Ubuntu installation, workspace names have little visibility, and there is no user exposed way to rename them. Still, they can be renamed using the `gsettings` command, e.g:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences workspace-names "['Browser', 'Terminal', 'Word', 'Games','Settings']"
```

or using dconf editor.

To reset to the default, issue the command:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences workspace-names
```

Extensions may expose the setting. The official Gnome Shell extension [Workspace Indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/21/workspace-indicator/) by fmuellner (part of Classical Gnome) exposes an option to rename the workspaces.